# deleting cronjob that shouldn't be there

Tags: cron, debian

I installed froxlor a while back and uninstalled it again, because it didn't fit my need. the server I'm running is a debian web server. after inspecting the system log file using

```
grep CRON /var/log/syslog
```

I noticed that there are still some froxlor things going on.

most noticable are log entries like:

```
Jun 25 10:55:01 v220200220072109810 CRON[5633]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/nice -n 5 /usr/bin/php -q /var/www/froxlor/scripts/froxlor_master_cronjob.php --tasks 1> /dev/null)
Jun 25 11:00:01 v220200220072109810 CRON[5727]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/nice -n 5 /usr/bin/php -q /var/www/froxlor/scripts/froxlor_master_cronjob.php --tasks 1> /dev/null)
```

however, when inspecting the crontab for the root user, I don't have any active crontabs. Any ideas on how to fix this issue?

Comment: please move this question to https://serverfault.com/ . SO is more about programing and coding, and this is a question regarding server and services.

Comment: There are a lot of files on debian system that execute cronjobs please take a look into /etc/cron.d/ /etc/cron.daily/ /etc/cron.hourly/ /etc/cron.monthly etc/